# String literals in sizeof

Tags: c

From my knowledge, string literals are stored in system-protected areas when used in executable code and not initialization. Does this also hold when using string literals in the sizeof function for example:

```
sizeof("example")
```

Is this string (char array) even created in memory and if not, where is it created and how does it get the correct result of 8 including the nul character?

Comment: The `sizeof` expression is resolved at compile time.  There is no need for the string to be in the object file for this case.

Comment: Detail: "sizeof function" is better as "sizeof operator" like `~` or `!`.  Could have used `sizeof "example"`.

Comment: user737163, "how does it get the correct result of 8 including the nul character?" --> what value where you expecting?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is an expected result but my question is how it gets to the result.

Comment: user737163 Count the characters and add 1 for the _null character_.  A more illustrative example, like `"abcdef"`, would use a literal than does not have size 4 or 8, to help distinguish it from a pointer size.

Comment: A string literal ([C11 6.4.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5)) is an array of `N` char (with `N` just enough for all the chars and an [extra] terminating `'\0'`) ... so `"example"` has type `/*readonly*/char [8]`, `"foo\0"` has type `/*readonly*/char[5]`, `"foo\0bar"` has type `/*readonly*/char[8]`

Comment: You seem to be asking, "Where will the string be stored, in memory, at runtime?"  But that's not the right question to ask, because it's not important to know how the string is represented at runtime.  The compiler has its own, very different, ways of representing your program at compile time.  `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, so the in-memory representation won't matter.  Clearly, the compiler has all the information it needs to determine the size of this constant string.  It probably won't be stored in memory at runtime at all.

Answer (score 3):

Being the operand of `sizeof` has no effect on where string literals are stored:

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
> ...
> 2     The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. ***The size is determined from the type of
> the operand***. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.

IOW, `sizeof` doesn't care where something is stored, because it's not looking at storage; it's looking at the *type* of its operand.  You can apply `sizeof` to things that have no storage like arithmetic expressions and numeric literals:

```
sizeof 100      == sizeof (int)
sizeof (2 * 3)  == sizeof (int)
sizeof (x + y)  == sizeof (whatever the common type of x and y is)
```

A string literal like `"foo"` has the *type* "4-element array of `char`" (3 characters plus the terminator), so `sizeof "foo"` evaluates to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard says nothing about this. It's all up to the compiler.

Most likely the string will not be part of the program but we can't know.

Nitpick: Since the result of `sizeof("example")` isn't used even that won't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the special case where `sizeof` is applied to a variable-length array, it is always evaluated at compile-time. The C standard doesn't force compilers to *not* allocate the string literal in your example, but in practice every compiler I know of will not do so. Instead they will replace the whole expression with the number `8` in the machine code.

Furthermore, note that the operand of `sizeof` isn't evaluated for side effects either. So code like `sizeof("example" + i++);` will not increment `i`. That's where tricks like `type* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);` come from: the `sizeof` expression is evaluated at compile-time, without ever de-referencing the pointer.